# Add host to service bus form getting error while configuring the workflow manager

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager, service-bus

Add host to service bus form getting error while configuring the workflow manager, 
please find the below log info.

> [Error] [12/10/2018 4:53:55 PM]:
>   System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Starting
>   service Service Bus Message Broker failed: Time out has expired and
>   the operation has not been completed. --->
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.Exceptions.OperationFailedException:
>   Starting service Service Bus Message Broker failed: Time out has
>   expired and the operation has not been completed.    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.SCMHelper.StartService(String
>   serviceName, Nullable`1 waitTimeout, String hostName)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.ServiceBusConfigHelper.StartSBServices(String
>   hostName, Nullable`1 waitTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.AddSBHost.ProcessRecordImplementation() 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()    at
>   System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command
>   command, Action`3 updateProgress)    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.AddSBNode(FarmCreationModel
>   model, Boolean isFirstCommand)

Please help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

this message is guiding towards port availability, looks like port 9000 is not avaiable for service bus, that's why it is throwing time out error.

- At this point collect the netstat information, run this in command line `netstat -ano| findstr 9000`)
- Check if the port 9000 is being used by any other application, if yes
- Re run the Config wizard and change the service bus port from 9000 to some other custom number.

Read more here: [Workflow manager Configuration failure: Step ‘Add host to Service Bus farm’ failed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2014/11/19/workflow-manager-configuration-failure-step-add-host-to-service-bus-farm-failed/)

Comment: I have checked this port 9000 is not available for any service. Please let me know is there any other possibilities?